# how to select only top 20 percent of data depending upon four other column in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

i have very large dataset I only want to select only top 20 percent values of Revenue (Native)  based on four other column Hyper ,Month ,Year ,Bedroom. like if we have 20 Revenue (Native) values of 1 bedroom in january 2021 in dubai downtown i only want to take top 4. how i do this in R?

```
 structure(list(Bedrooms = c(3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 2), Month = c("January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January"), Year = c(2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021), `Occupancy Rate` = c(0.48, 0.35, 
0.16, 0.45, 0.36, 0.1), `Revenue (Native)` = c(97335.56, 80048.43, 
68867.55, 63505.68, 62760.82, 56774.9), `ADR (Native)` = c(6489.04, 
6670.7, 4591.17, 4536.12, 5705.53, 4367.3), Hyper = c("Dubai Downtown", 
"Dubai Downtown", "Dubai Downtown", "Dubai Downtown", "Dubai Downtown", 
"Dubai Downtown")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: In the dput , there is no Net Rental column

Comment: Do you want `df1 %>% group_by(Hyper, Month, Year) %>% mutate(NetRental = mean(Bedrooms)) %>% slice_max(order_by = NetRental, prop = 0.20) %>% ungroup`